# Update with a Select

Tags: mysql, sql, select, sql-update

How can I update StatusID in Table X using Table Y?

Table X has SourceID and old StatusID
Table Y has SourceID and new StatusID

```
update x
set StatusID= (select StatusID from Y)
where
SourceID = (select SourceID from Y)
```

Is this right? I'm afraid to run the query in case it messes everything up....

I am using joins to get the StatusID for table Y, so I think I need to use a `SELECT`.

This is how I'm getting SourceID and StatusID for table Y

```
select  t2.Sourceid,  t3.ActionID
from tblSource t2 
right join  Y t1 on t1.BaselineSourceKey= t2.tempSourceID
 right join lkuActionCode t3
       on t3.actioncode = CASE 
       WHEN t1.actionCode  = 'R' THEN 'N' 
       WHEN t1.actionCode  = 'B' THEN 'R' 
       WHEN t1.actionCode  = 'A' THEN 'R' 
       WHEN t1.actionCode  = 'E' THEN 'N' 
       WHEN t1.actionCode  = 'F' THEN 'S' 
       WHEN t1.actionCode  = 'G' THEN 'S' 
       WHEN t1.actionCode  = 'K' THEN 'DP' 
       WHEN t1.actionCode  = 'Q' THEN 'C' 
       WHEN t1.actionCode  = 'S' THEN 'AER' 
       WHEN t1.actionCode  = 'T' THEN 'AEN' 
       WHEN t1.actionCode  = 'U' THEN 'C' 
       WHEN t1.actionCode  = 'V' THEN 'UR'
    WHEN t1.actionCode  = 'W' THEN 'R'             
        END
    where actionid <> 10 and actionid <> 8 and actionid <> 3
```

Comment: What exactly are you trying to do?  Populate a new column or keep data agreeing with each other?

Comment: what are you going to do if this `select StatusID from Y` queries more than one row of data?

Comment: What you posted is the most supported means of updating a table based on the value from another.  MySQL and SQL Server are the only databases I'm aware of that support JOINs in UPDATE syntax.

Comment: I updated the question, please look

Comment: Is there any reason you can't back up the database, run it, and then restore the backup if everything goes badly?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This could be simpler

```
update x
set StatusID= Y.StatusID
from Y
where y.SourceID = X.SourceID
```

If it is Access, then you could use

```
update x inner join y on y.sourceid=x.sourceid
set x.statusid = y.statusid
```

Comment: no it's sql, but where do i use my select to get the right data out from table Y?

Comment: i ended up making a temp table with the query above, and updating my table with your suggestion, thanks

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure that works.  Try:

```
update x set StatusID=Y.StatusID
from Y where (x.SourceID=Y.SourceID);
```

ETA:  This should work in PostgreSQL, but I'm not sure about other SQL dialects.

Answer (score 2):

```
update x
set StatusID = y.StatusID
from x
join y on x.SourceID= y.SourceID
```

Answer (score 1):

**UPDATED**
In SQL Server you can do this:

```
UPDATE A
SET A.StatusID= B.StatusId
FROM TableX AS A
JOIN TableY AS B
ON A.SourceID = B.SourceID
```

In your updated question, now you are just doing a `SELECT`, it's not gonna update any record at all. What database enginge are you using?

Comment: SQL 2005. the Select that i am showing gets the SourceID and the new ActionID that i then need to update table X with. but i can't figure out how to do it....

Comment: @xrum Is there a reason for all the `RIGHT JOINS`?, cause eventually you can have sourceid NULL on the output of your `SELECT`

Answer (score 1):

```
update x, y 
  set x.StatusID=y.StatusID 
  where x.SourceID=y.SourceID
```

Comment: I am using joins to get the StatusID for table X, so i think i need to use a select.